# Javascript replace regex wildcard with dynamic text

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I need to extract text but some parts are dynamic and change

This is my var

```
htts://query1.data.site.com/v7/finance/download/MYTEXT?period1=1664641287&period2=1696177287&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true
```

I need to take only `MYTEXT`

These values changes

```
MYTEXT
1664641287
1696177287
1d
```

I tried with `string.replace` but I don't know how to remove the dynamic parts

The solution I thought of was to remove all the text before and after MYTEXT but I can't write a command that can do this

Comment: Have you tried using [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)? It can parse the path and query params for you

Comment: if the format is always the same `i=str.indexOf('?');j=str.lastIndexOf('/',i);s=str.slice(j+1,i);`

Comment: That string almost looks like a URL.  Except I've never heard of the `htts` scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `URL` to parse URL strings.

You can get the `pathname` to extract `MYTEXT`, which will be the last segment separated by `/`'s.

You can get the `searchParams` to retrieve the value of specific query parameters like `period1=1664641287`

```js
const urlString = 'htts://query1.data.site.com/v7/finance/download/MYTEXT?period1=1664641287&period2=1696177287&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true';

const url = new URL(urlString);

// You can get the last segment of the path like this 
console.log(url.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0]);

// You can also get query params like this if you need them
console.log(url.searchParams.get('period1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp that matches everything between the last `/` and `?`

```js
const url = 'htts://query1.data.site.com/v7/finance/download/MYTEXT?period1=1664641287&period2=1696177287&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true';
const regexp = /[^\/]+(?=\?)/;
match = url.match(regexp);
console.log(match);
```